# How do I replicate LOBs in Kafka?

Tags: cdc

Using IBM CDC to replicate `LOBs` to `Kafka` does not work with default parameters.

The error I get is:

> KafkaTargetBinaryWriter_BinaryWriter_0{119} com.datamirror.ts.target.apply.kafka.KafkaTargetBinaryWriterJob$KafkaProducerCallback onCompletion()
>  
>   The message is 10000000 bytes when serialized which is larger than the maximum request size you have configured with the max.request.size configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The following link explain IDR CDC Kafka Replication Engine parameters affecting LOB replication.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSTRGZ_11.4.0/com.ibm.cdcdoc.mcadminguide.doc/concepts/applyprocesssystemparametersKafka.html

In the provided example, they configured it to support messages of up to 16MB.

I hope this help.